# Linked Ads not being tracked on SPA website despite activity being measured

Tags: single-page-application, linkedin-api, tracking

For a client we are running a Linkedin Ads campaign. The client has an SPA website. The trigger for the conversion is the visit to a specific URL. In the campaign overview we can see that there is activity, so the conversions are being tracked. The problem is that the number of conversions stays at "0" even though there is activity being seen when i check the "status".

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

We created the conversions through GTM and in the default Linkedin conversion creator, but still no luck.